# Automate refunds on failed In-App transactions

Tags: android, in-app-billing

In the case where a user pays for an In-App item and there is an error on the server, I would like to be able to send a message to Google to refund it automatically.

For example, in a weird (and extremely improbable) circumstance where the package name does not correspond to what you expect at the server. You cancel the order there and I should be able to tell Google that the transaction was strange, and that it should be immediately refunded.

At the moment, I can only return to the client that there was weirdness, and that the order did not go through as expected.

Comment: And what did you try so far? Show us your code

Comment: At the moment, I only have a standard generic Android in-app billing system with a PHP server back end. I haven't tried anything yet, because I couldn't find any relevant documentation.

Comment: As far as I know there's no API for Wallet Merchant refunds. You can dig into the refund flow and check which methods all called on Google backend. With oauth authorized calls it should not be a problem to invoke it programmatically.

Comment: OK - I had worried that would be the case. Still, at the end of the day. It isn't really a case I need to worry about. If an error is set, I can get users to contact me. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.ö

Comment: Better wait for an answer that contains some code showing how to invoke a method that cancels an order